# Проверка ходов в шахматах

Tags: java, javafx, шахматы

Пишу код для шахмат. Столкнулся с проблемой определения корректности хода EnPassant у пешки, то есть, когда вражеская пешка "прыгает" на две клетки и её стоит сразу бить ответным ходом, иначе теряется возможность совершить EnPassant. Не понимаю, как отобразить это в коде, отслеживать ходы всех своих фигур?

Comment: кто нибудь да прочитает. Но без кода помочь не получится, т.к. нет ни какой информации о логическом представлении данных (фигурах, пешках, ходах и самом поле). Дополните вопрос кодом (или хотя бы необходимой его частью).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ввести, так называемый флаг (переменную типа `boolean`) `enPassantable` которая будет отвечать за возможность данного хода. Тогда условия хода En Passant будет определяться следующим способом:

```
if(пешка стоит на определенной горизонтали && 
   enPassantable для пешки противника == true &&
   пешка противника стоит справа или слева) {}
```

Теперь как же менять этот флажок. Если пешка ходит на две клетки, то `enPassantable = true`. После того, как противник сделал ход нужно пройтись по всем пешкам (или пешки у которых `enPassantable = true` хранить где-то в отдельном списке) и присвоить `enPassantable = false`. Таким образом, следующим ходом противник не сможет сделать данный ход, так как `enPassantable` будет уже `false`.

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз то, что нужно. Буду реализовывать в этом направлении.